# Lambda in front of exponential function

Tags: python, exponential

In the following case I'm very confused as to why there is a `lam` in front of the expression in line 3. Could someone please clarify  what this lambda does?

```
lam = 0.5
x = np.arange(0, 15, 0.1)
y = lam * np.exp(-lam * x)
```

Comment: Isn't `lam` just `0.5`?

Answer (score 2):

It's the coefficient of the probability density function of the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

It's `lam`, not `lambda`. Since the first line is `lam = 0.5`, `lam * np.exp(-lam * x)` is multiplying the result of `np.exp(-lam * x)` by `0.5`.